# Android kotlin - app stopps when check if GPS is enabled

Tags: java, android, kotlin, gps, location

This is the code:

```
        val gps_enabled = locationManager!!.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)

        if(!gps_enabled) {
            Log.d("letsSee", "GPS IS OFF")
        }else{
            Log.d("letsSee", "GPS IS ON")
        }
```

The app crashes when I try to check for GPS whether it's on or off. Everything works fine without the check but I still need to check it!
Any ideas?

```
09-16 03:59:12.533 32454-32454/com.amoflirt.amoflirt E/dalvikvm: Could not find class 'android.graphics.drawable.RippleDrawable', referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.hasOverlappingRendering
09-16 03:59:13.713 32454-32454/com.amoflirt.amoflirt E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
        at com.amoflirt.amoflirt.MainActivity.getLocation(MainActivity.kt:95)
        at com.amoflirt.amoflirt.MainActivity$onCreate$3.onClick(MainActivity.kt:67)
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4475)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18786)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5419)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1046)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:862)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: None without the stacktrace.

Comment: Is it supposed to be somewhere under error or verbose?

Comment: It'll be an error-level log block.

Comment: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException this is referred to the val gps.. line

Comment: Please post the entire error, as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: There's an error message above the text you posted. Can you copy that in too? If you tell Android Studio to only look at the current application, it's easier to find your logs.

Comment: Ok now I reduced it to "Show only selected application" and this is all which is in error, check edit pls

Comment: Is there no "caused by" line?

Comment: Also, how is `locationManager` initialized. KotlinNullPointerException usually means a variable that you tell the compiler isn't null ends up being null. Since you've told Kotlin that `locationManager` isn't null with the `!!`, I'm guessing there's a problem with the initialization.

Comment: No, not in error or verbose

Comment: It depends on when you call `getLocation()`. It could be possible that when you click that View (is it a Button?), `locationManager` hasn't yet been defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `locationManager` has been defined before you access it.

As a sidenote, you might be able to use Kotlin's lazy init:

```
val locationManager by lazy { //however you define it normally }
```

That will only initialize it once it's first accessed, and then keep that instance for the lifetime of the class.